# Compiling PHP with apache mod_php on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-httpd, php5

I need to compile PHP with apache module on Kubuntu.

I have installed both apache2 and apache2-dev. But I am unable to locate apxs2 nor apxs.

```
$ uname -a
Linux hppavilion 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ dpkg -l | grep apache
ii  apache2                                         2.4.18-2ubuntu3                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  apache2-bin                                     2.4.18-2ubuntu3                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apache2-data                                    2.4.18-2ubuntu3                            all          Apache HTTP Server (common files)
ii  apache2-dev                                     2.4.18-2ubuntu3                            amd64        Apache HTTP Server (development headers)
ii  apache2-utils                                   2.4.18-2ubuntu3
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Pick one of the sites and delete the question from the other. If you want to keep this one, include the details from your question on SO. If not, one or both will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Debian-testing system, `apxs` is indeed part of `apache2-dev` package. `dpkg-query -L apache2-dev` shows what files live inside of apache2-dev package. Could you check this? (this should be a comment, but I cannot comment due to low reputation).

Comment: I searched using `locate` and could not find it but `dpkg-query` lists it. I am also seeing both `/usr/bin/apxs2` and `/usr/bin/apxs`. It's not clear which one to be be used when compiling PHP.

Comment: I found out the APXS vs. APXS2. It can be found at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/apxs-loadmodule. There is also an explanation at http://serverfault.com/questions/435020/apxs2-is-missing-so-i-cant-install-apache-mod-x-sendfile